# "This key is already associated with an element of this collection" and Runtime Error 457

Tags: vba, excel

Original Post: 
Data being indexed in the dictionary is verified to have no duplicate values in the index column. 
Data in range has format: col 1 = index(string) | col 2 = value(double)
All values set to 0 prior to runtime of this section of code
Error trapping is set to "Break on Unhandled Errors"

Why am I getting this error? I can't spot anything that would throw a duplicate into the dictionary. (Sorry, I'm not a developer.)

Update:
No longer getting the duplicate key error, but now seeing values added to the dictionary (and subsequently output) as keys, in addition to the desired index keys. Apologies if this is a big ol' bowl of spaghetti.
Full code below

```
Sub CompileActuals()
' Get it started
Dim ibh As Integer
Dim pah As Integer
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim RngB As Range
Dim RngA As Range
Dim CLine As Object
Dim CLineData As Class1
Dim im As Integer
Dim cm As Integer
Dim vpah As Integer
Dim vibh As Integer
Dim vMonth As Integer
Dim vO As Integer
Dim LineWeight As Double
Dim varIndex As Variant

ibh = Sheets("GCM Compiler").Cells(1, 6)
pah = Sheets("GCM Compiler").Cells(2, 6)
im = Sheets("GCM Compiler").Cells(3, 4)
cm = Sheets("GCM Compiler").Cells(1, 4)

Set WrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GCM Compiler")
Set RngB = WrkSht.Range(Cells(9, 4 + (2 * im)), Cells(1563, 5 + (2 * im)))
Set RngA = WrkSht.Range(Cells(9, 3), Cells(8 + pah, 4))
Set CLine = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Wipe Budget Numbers
Range(Cells(9, (5 + (2 * im))), Cells(8 + ibh, 5 + (2 * im))).Value = 0
' Clear the Dictionary
CLine.RemoveAll

' Fill dictionary with zeros for the existing indices
For vibh = 1 To ibh
    ' Set each row's variables
    varIndex = RngB.Cells(vibh, 1).Value
    LineWeight = CDbl(RngB.Cells(vibh, 2).Value)
    vMonth = cm

    ' Test for index already exists in dictionary
    If CLine.Exists(varIndex) Then
        ' Get existing index entry's properties
        Set CLineData = CLine(varIndex)
        ' Add weight of that line to the index entry
        CLineData.Weight = 0

    Else
        ' Create an entry for the new index
        Set CLineData = New Class1
        ' Set properties of the new entry
        CLineData.Weight = LineWeight
        CLineData.Month = vMonth
        CLineData.Index = varIndex
        ' Store the new entry in the dictionary
        CLine.Add varIndex, CLineData

    End If

Next vibh

' Add actuals, iterate thru pasted actual values
For vpah = 1 To pah
    ' Set each row's variables
    varIndex = RngA.Cells(vpah, 1).Value
    LineWeight = CDbl(RngA.Cells(vpah, 2).Value)
    vMonth = cm

    ' Test for index already exists in dictionary
    If CLine.Exists(varIndex) Then
        ' Get existing index entry's properties
        Set CLineData = CLine(varIndex)
        ' Add weight of that line to the index entry
        CLineData.Weight = CLineData.Weight + CDbl(RngA.Cells(vpah, 2))

    Else
        ' Create an entry for the new index
        Set CLineData = New Class1
        ' Set properties of the new entry
        CLineData.Weight = LineWeight
        CLineData.Month = vMonth
        CLineData.Index = varIndex
        ' Store the new entry in the dictionary
        CLine.Add varIndex, CLineData

    End If

Next vpah

' Output Compiled Weights
For vO = 0 To CLine.Count - 1
    Set CLineData = CLine.Items()(vO)
    WrkSht.Cells(9 + vO, 4 + (2 * im)).Value = CLineData.Index
    WrkSht.Cells(9 + vO, 5 + (2 * im)).Value = CLineData.Weight
Next vO


'
End Sub
```

Data comes in in two ranges, budget and actuals. The goal of the code is to replace the budget with zeros then compile actuals of existing key items and of new key items and add the data to the original location of the budget data.

Both the actuals and the budget input data ranges will look something like this with index in the first column and associated value in the second column:
Key 1 | Value
Key 2 | Value
Key 3 | Value
Key 1 | Value
Key 4 | Value

Comment: You look through `RngB` rows (once for each row up to `ibh`). The first column in `RngB` holds what will become the Key in the `CLine` dictionary. Search whatever that range is for duplicate values.

Comment: You could easily solve that yourself by looking what value `varIndex` has when the error happens. On contrary, we cannot help you without having your data.

Comment: I added a simple if else to find out what was being stored in the index, and found the varIndex also included the values from the second column, which did include dupes. Based on the code, the varIndex should only be getting set from the first column. Why do I have column 2 data getting set as the varIndex?

Comment: @MrSneaki Apparently because your `RngB` is a range that has your second column as its first column. E.g. if the first column is A, the second column is B, and `RngB` is `B1:B100`, then `RngB.Cells(1, 1).Value` is the value from `B1`. In fact you even named the thing Rng**B**.

Comment: @GSerg is the name RngB causing the issue? Because I defined the range as a two column range: [Set RngB = WrkSht.Range(Cells(9, 4 + (2 * im)), Cells(1563, 5 + (2 * im)))]
where im is always > 0

Comment: The name is not causing the issue. What is causing the issue is that apparently you are off by one in your column count.

Comment: @GSerg well the dictionary seems to be storing both columns' rows as keys, as the first (actual target) column is also outputting varIndex lines and values.
Appreciate the help, thanks for bearing with me

Comment: What is the value for `RngB.Address` and `RngA.Address`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
 If Not .Exists(SomeKey) Then 
        .Add SomeKey, SomeValue
Else
    stop 'Go investigate what someKey is
End If
```

Also I suggest checking out the excellent article at https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html

Comment: thanks for the tip and the shared article.
Any advice on my recent comment? Seeing values I don't want to add showing up added as varIndex entries.

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough to go on: You're going to have to amend your post to include some sample data as well as to show how variables are being populated.

Comment: Not much advice we can give here other than use F8 to step through your code, and inspect what value varIndex takes when you get something unexpected. Then work out how varIndex was populated.